# How to show a set of polynomials is algebraically independent?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose that I have $n$ homogeneous polynomials $f_1, \dots, f_n \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ and that $n < m$.  Is there a well known method or algorithm to determine if these polynomials are algebraically independent?

As far as I know the Jacobian criterion works only for the case where $n=m$.

Comment: You can consider the equations $f_i=t_i$ with new variables $t_i$, and eliminate the $x$'s using Groebner bases.

Comment: (This is explained, if I recall correctly, in Cox's book on Varieties, Ideals and algorithms)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The polynomials are algebraically independent if and only if
$$
df_1 \wedge df_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_n 
$$
is not identically zero. In other words, you have only to check that 
one of the maximal minors of the matrix $\left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Can you give a proof?

Comment: Martin, in char. 0 the map $f:\mathbf{A}^m \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^n$ is smooth on a dense open in the source if and only if it is dominant, and such generic smoothness is equivalent to generic injectivity of the induced map $f^{\ast}(\Omega^1_{\mathbf{A}^n/k}) \rightarrow \Omega^1_{\mathbf{A}^m/k}$.  But at the generic point, such injectivity can be checked between $n$th exterior powers. 

Answer (score 5):

Hi there.  A Groebner basis based algorithm that also produces an annihilating polynomial in case the polynomials are algebraically dependent can be found on the Singular site at

http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/3-0-2/sing_534.htm .